# How do I set the ID in a link_to tag in haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I've tried

```
= link_to 'foo', :action => 'bar', :id => 'foobar'
```

But ID only seems to modify the href, resulting in

```
<a href="controller/foobar/bar">foo</a>
```

How do I set the ID correctly? Also can someone explain to me why :id is modifying the href just so I can understand what's going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to put `:action => 'bar'` inside a hash.

```
= link_to 'foo', { :action => 'bar' }, :id => 'foobar'
```

There is an example in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) that put an example with your same problem:

> *Classes and ids for CSS are easy to produce:*

```
link_to "Articles", articles_path, :id => "news", :class => "article"
# => <a href="/articles" class="article" id="news">Articles</a>
```

> *Be careful when using the older argument style, as an extra literal
>   hash is needed:*

```
link_to "Articles", { :controller => "articles" }, :id => "news", 
    :class => "article"
# => <a href="/articles" class="article" id="news">Articles</a>
```

> *Leaving the hash off gives the wrong link:*

```
link_to "WRONG!", :controller => "articles", :id => "news", :class => "article"
# => <a href="/articles/index/news?class=article">WRONG!</a>
```

This is why you it's better to use the new argument style, with alias for the routes, more than calling controllers and actions explicitly.

Comment: It's seems that it doesn't work at all.. My code `<%= link_to "Cancel edit", { :controller => "statement_email_notifications", :action => "edit", :id => @statement_email_notification.id }, :class => "btn btn-success", :id => "cancel-edit-button" %>` and it get id as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

Can you use path helpers for this?  This would be dependent upon your routes being configured correctly.

So for example:

`= link_to "foo", foo_path, :id => "foobar"`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters with `link_to` tag like

```
= link_to "foo", { :controller => "foo", :id => "foobar"}
```

or

```
= link_to "foo", {:action=> "any-action, ":controller => "foo", :id => "foobar"}
```

here you can no of parameters with link _tag